# Divided Road In ArcGIS Network Dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, here-maps

I built a network dataset with HERE data using Street Data Processing Tools v10.3.1.1. The dataset built fine, but I'm seeing some issues with the route making a left turn onto a divided highway. I've looked at the area on Google Street View, and there is indeed a concrete barrier dividing the highway, which should prevent a left turn onto the highway. When I look at the attribute table, it appears to have the right values in the DIVIDER field. I cannot for the life of me figure out why the route doesn't seem to take into account divided roads.

[image: Divided Road Turn]

[image: Divided Road Streetview]